# What are the two beeps my iPhone makes before bluetooth connection is made in this video?

Tags: iphone, applications, audio, bluetooth

See the video here: https://youtu.be/RDEszGStvjY

I'm using an app called Zello, and triggering a walkie talkie message using a bluetooth button called a Pryme BT-PTT-Z.

In the video you can hear that the iPhone makes 2 beeps before the louder tone that means zello is starting to record my message. What are these 2 beeps and how do I turn them off?

The crazy thing is that I have tried the same app and button with several other iPhones running the same software, and those phones don't make this sound! I've even tried other walkie talkie apps and they have the same issue. Therefore, there must be something specific to my device or iOS settings.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post link for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed.  You can also contact the software developer for assistance with their product.

Comment: This sound is an iOS issue, not an issue with the application on the phone. As noted, this sound happens on several apps on my phone when i trigger something via bluetooth, which must mean there is some setting or apple issue occuring!

Comment: Your question is a bit difficult to understand but your comment helps clarify it.  I'll remove the close vote.